# Excel : if listbox value n2 is selected, change another cell's value

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

So basically, I have a listbox (named ListBox1) with 4 values (let's call them "value1", "value2", etc). What I want to do is the following pseudocode :

```
if (value1 is selected)
    then change the formula in cell A1 to "=B1/B2"
elseif (value2 is selected)
    then change the formula in cell A1 to "=ROUND(B1/B2,0)"
elseif (value3 is selected)
    then change the formula in cell A1 to "=ROUNDUP(B1/B2,0)"
elseif (value4 is selected)
    then change the formula in cell A1 to "=ROUNDDOWN(B1/B2,0)"
```

(Using a macro would be the best please)

It seems really simple, but I can't find any tutorial that would tell me how to do this anywhere.

I tried this :

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    If ListBox1.Selected("value1") Then range("A1").Formula = "=B1/B2"
    ElseIf ListBox1.Selected("value2") Then range("A1).value = "=ROUND(B1/B2,0)"
    ' so on so forth
    EndIf
End Sub
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do it simple:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
  If ListBox1.Selected(0) Then Range("A1").Formula = "=B1/B2"
  If ListBox1.Selected(1) Then Range("A1").Formula = "=ROUND(B1/B2,0)"
  If ListBox1.Selected(2) Then Range("A1").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(B1/B2,0)"
  If ListBox1.Selected(3) Then Range("A1").Formula = "=ROUNDDOWN(B1/B2,0)"
End Sub
```

or a different way:

```
Range("A1").Formula = Array("=B1/B2","=ROUND(B1/B2,0)","=ROUNDUP(B1/B2,0)","=ROUNDDOWN(B1/B2,0)")(ListBox1.ListIndex)
```

for your case:
you have set up a range for the values in the box.
set the output to `A1`. Then set a macro to the listbox: (select "New")

```
Sub Listbox_OnChange()
  Range("A1").Formula = Array("", "=B1/B2", "=ROUND(B1/B2,0)", "=ROUNDUP(B1/B2,0)", "=ROUNDDOWN(B1/B2,0)")(Range("A1").Value)
End Sub
```

The main problem is that your ListBox isn't a *real* ListBox and also can't be used like one. You need to use an ActiveXObject to do it like the first part in my answer.

Comment: None seem to be working. Just to check, to define the name as ListBox1, I have to do it in the fiel in the upper left part of my screen where I can define the names of cells, right ?

Comment: BTW, when debugging, this is highlighted : If ListBox1.Value = "value1" Then

Comment: you still ned to trigger the code (via button or change_event or whatever)... also, is the listbox in the sheet or in a form?

Comment: It's from "Form Control", and in format control, the input range is a column of my sheet. How do I do this with change_event please ?

Comment: Still doesn't work, `If ListBox1.Selected(0) Then` still gets highlighted by debugger. :/

Comment: And by the way, your 2nd proposal also breaks (the whole line is highlighted). It says "object required"

Comment: I think the problem lies with the `ListBox1` part, how do I make sure this is indeed the name of the list box ?

Comment: @Malimalo added a new part to my answer, please try it

Comment: Sooo... It alsmot works (thanks !) : when I click (in the listbox) on `value2` for instance, `A1`'s formula is changed as it should. BUT : then the selector jumps to the last value of the list (but does not change the formula on `A1`). And if I try to select that last value, the formula in A1 doesn't change. Any idea why and how to stop it from behaving this way ?

Comment: @Malimalo it should not change the selected item on its own... just for a quick check: when creating a new listbox and doing the same, does it also jump to the last value?

Comment: I created another listbox and changed everything so that it's the same as the original one, and it behaves the same way, yes. (I'm not sure if this helps. If you're trying to figure out if there are other macros acting on this listbox, the answer is no :) )

Comment: @Malimalo i'm completely confused... the only solution i can imagine for now is increasing the input-range by one row (having the last item as an empty string) which is not used,,, you could use your 4 values this way, but it would still be buggy :/

Comment: So am I. Yes, that's what I did for now. Called the fourth row "this thing is buggy", hope the people who will use it will understand :p... Thank you for your help anyway ! EDIT : oh, didn't see your last part about the ActiveXObject, I'm gonna try it and I'll tell you.

Comment: Alright, I managed to do it another way, see my answer if curious :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it without going through VBA code. I had the list box point to cell `A2` and change it's value to either `value1`, `value2`, etc.

Then, in cell A1 :

```
=IF(A2="value1";B1/B2;
  IF(A2="value2";ROUND(B1/B2;0);
    IF(A2="value3";ROUNDUP(B1/B2;0);
      IF(A2="value4";ROUNDDOWN(B1/B2;0);"")
    )
  )
)
```